# How to execute one command in multiples directories using "GNU parallel"?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Every day I have to update a bunch of repositories and also execute in some of them another command (from CARTON, Perl module dependency manager). I use always a loop to do that but I want do it parallely with **GNU parallel** if it is possible but I don't understand so well its [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

The point more similar I've read that can help me is called **"Running the same commands on all hosts"** so I got into the directory with all repos and I tried to execute: `parallel --onall carton` but I don't know if it works or not. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Show the code you use now (i.e. your loop).

Comment: To update repositories: for REPO in `ls`; do ( cd "$REPO"; git pull) ; done;

To update dependencies: for REPO in `ls`; do ( cd "$REPO"; carton) ; done;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
parallel 'cd {} && git pull' ::: *
parallel 'cd {} && carbon' ::: *
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. Also, thanks to this [document](http://wiki.scinethpc.ca/wiki/images/7/7b/Tech-talk-gnu-parallel.pdf) I could understood better the syntax.